# creating a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

```
    keyMain= new Key_Node[X];
    for(int i=0; i<X; i++)
    {
        keyMain[i].key=i;
        cout << keyMain[i].key<<endl;
        keyMain[i].next_package=NULL;
    }
```

Am I doing it right here? I am not sure about it. It seems like the right thing to do, but can anybody confirm? Thank you.`X` is the number inputted by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do that, provided the array is not expected to grow or shrink.

Otherwise, `std::vector` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)) is probably a better choice. C++ provides some powerful collection classes in its standard library and everyone who professes to know the language should be familiar with them.

Comment: No, the array will be static throughout the course of the program. So my code would work, right?

Comment: Yes, it would work as-is, given your comment. Just be careful of using the word static (unchanging) - "static" has a specific meaning in C++ unrelated to its common definition.